# Dynamically casting classes 

Tags: c#

```
 class Base
    {
        virtual public void FuncA()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("10");
        }
    }

    public class BasePlusOne: Base
    {
        public void Bp1MEthod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BasePlusOne");
        }
        override public  void FuncA()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("overridden by BasePlusTwo");
        }
    }


    public class BasePlusTwo : Base
    {
        public void Bp1MEthod()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("BasePlusTwo");
        }
        override public void FuncA()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("overridden by BasePlusTwo");
        }
    }


    public class One
    {
        public Base GetBase(int i )
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                return new BasePlusOne();
            }
            else
            {
                 return new BasePlusTwo();
            }
        }
    }


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            One one = new One();
            Base bp =one.GetBase(2);

            BasePlusOne b = (BasePlusOne)bp;

            b.Bp1MEthod();
            b.FuncA();
        }
    }
```

As seen I'm using the following code to dynamically select the `base` class. I am casting the `base` class received to the appropriate one . This code will throw exception if the returned class is `BasePlusOne`. Is there any better method to handle this scenario? Is there any other fault with this approach?

```
One one = new One();
Base bp =one.GetBase(2);

BasePlusOne b = (BasePlusOne)bp;

b.Bp1MEthod();
b.FuncA();
```

Comment: To get a good answer, please provide more context around what you are trying to do.

Comment: edited the question.  please recheck.

Answer (score 2):

You can test the type of the object with `is` operator:

```
if (obj is BasePlusOne) // this should be first
{
   BaseBlusOne b = obj as BaseBluseOne;
}
else if (obj is Base)
{
   Base b = obj as Base;
}
```

Notice the order of `if`s. If class `BasePlusONe` inherits `Base`, then the order must be like the obove. If the first was `Base`, then it would be entered both by `Base` object and `BasePlustOno` (assuming that `BasePlusOne : Base`, as we said).

**Answer for your code**:

```
One one = new One();
Base bp = one.GetBase(2);

if (bp is BasePlusOne)
{
    BasePlusOne b = (BasePlusOne)bp;
    b.Bp1MEthod();
    b.FuncA();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm very much mistaken it sounds like you want to use the [strategy pattern...](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

EDIT - I haven't read all the code.... I'd use an interface to specify the common stuff as in the strategy pattern...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add `Bp1MEthod` to a common base-class (i.e. `Base`). Casting `BasePlusTwo` to `BasePlusOne` will (generally) fail.

Casting upwards (from `Base` to `BasePlusOne`) in the object ancestry is a bad idea and a strong hint for a flawed design. Casting in the other direction is the basic idea of polymorhism.